# Node.js route to a url with querystring

Tags: node.js, routes

My Node.js application sends a response to load the following url in an iframe

```
http://localhost:3000/fileloadsuccess.html?fname=abc.txt
```

I get the error

> EONET : no such file or directory exists

I have set the routing as

```
app.get('/fileloadsuccess.html?fname=:fid', function(req,res){
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/fileloadsuccess.html?fname=:fid');
});
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: You don't include query parameters in the *route*, you access them from the `req` object.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am not trying to access the querystring parameters, I am trying to construct an url and let that open inside an iframe linked to the application. I am assuming the error EONET is because it is not finding an appropriate route so there should be somethign wrong the way I have coded the routing. If I set the route to just fileloadsuccess.html it works. I intend to access the file name from the url string once the page opens up within the iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use query string parameters with res.sendFile().

You also could try so serve `fileloadsuccess.html` as static file:
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Or continue to use res.sendFile() like:

```
res.sendFile('fileloadsuccess.html', { root: __dirname });
```

To get query string parameters you can use `req.query`
http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query

Comment: Yep, we cannot use querystring parameters in the res.sendfile() method. I had to write a template using ejs and pass the values that i had intended to pass through the querystring to achieve what i wanted.